# Vanity, Rails 3 and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, vanity

I'm trying to get Vanity to play nicely with Heroku and my Rails 3 app. At the moment, it all works fine locally using Pow and a local Redis server, but when I push to Heroku using the RedisToGo add-on, nothing seems to get the server running, I just get the error: `getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`.

Here's my config/vanity.yml file:

```
staging:
  adapter: redis
  host: <%= ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] %>
```

and my config/initializers/redis.rb:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

I've also tried using the actual `redis://<actualusername>:actualpassword@actualserver.com:9274` and it gives the same error. I've also tried with and without the `redis://`.

Has anyone got Vanity working with Heroku and Rails 3? Am I missing something terribly obvious? My Google-fu has failed me thus far.

Comment: getaddrinfo usually means you have an incorrect host. Have you double checked that?

Comment: Yep. This is all being set by Heroku. The REDISTOGO_URL is set for me, and it works in the console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, it was something stupid, all right. You don't use `host`, you use `connection`.

```
staging:
  adapter: redis
  connection: <%= ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] %>
```

Hope this helps someone, because I nearly beat my computer to a pulp.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Postgres on Heroku you need to do things a bit different. Here is my hack (config/vanity.yml):

```
production:
  adapter: active_record
  active_record_adapter: postgresql

  <% username, password, host, database = ENV['DATABASE_URL'].scan(%r{//(.*):(.*)@(.*)/(.*)}).first %>
  host:     <%= host %>
  username: <%= username %>
  password: <%= password %>
  database: <%= database %>
```

And you have to force Vanity to not use the Redis adapter (a bug if you ask me). Put this in an initializer:

```
Vanity.playground.establish_connection(Rails.env.to_sym)
```

Comment: Do you know if Vanity uses its own connection pool to the database? If so, I have a feeling it will have contention with the app over the limited number of connections that Heroku provides.

Answer (score 3):

One final note: If you're using ActiveRecord & Postgres on Heroku and you ARE NOT on the shared database, the connection string should be:

```
username, password, host, port, database = ENV['DATABASE_URL'].scan(%r{//(.*):(.*)@(.*):(.*)/(.*)}).first
```

Comment: I did something like a u = Uri.parse(ENV['DATABASE_URL']); username = u.user just to be more straightforward.